# Inference arrival rate by samples of forward recurrence time for renewal process

Tags: inference, stochastic-processes

There is a regenerative renewal process with iid. inter arrival time $X$, which follow the distribution $F(x)$. $N(t)$ is the counting process and $S_{N(t)} = X_0+X_1+\dots+X_{N(t)-1}$ is the time that the $N(t)$th arrival time, with $S_0=0$.

But I don't know about $F(x)$. May be can only assume it is **not** a Exponential distribution. Or assume it in Pareto distribution.

What I have are samples of Forward Recurrence Time(FRT) $W_t = S_{N(t)+1} - t$ and it's corresponding $t$, which means that $t$ is not a constant. But $t$ is bounded value that all $t\leq\tau$.

I want to inference the arrival rate $\mu$ of the process, where $\mu=\frac{1}{E[X]}$.

If I have analytic model of FRT's distribution, I might fit the marginal distribution $G(w,t)$ by data, where $w$ is the waiting time to the next event start from time $t$.

However the distribution of FRT could not easily be got analytically. so that I could not fit the model exactly. Is there any relationship between the $\mu$ and $E[W_t]$ or $E[G(W,t)]$, so that I could use to estimate $\mu$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\ E[S_{N(t)+1}]=\mu*E[N(t)+1] $ and so $\ E[W_{t}]=\mu*E[N(t)+1]-t$. Just look at Karlin (page 184) but it stems from using a renewal argument solving $\ E[S_{N(t)+1}]$ conditioning on $X_{1}$ and then using the law of total probability to represent $\ E[S_{N(t)+1}]$ as the n-fold convolution. What I just explained was actually the Wald equation when $N(t)+1$ is viewed as the stopping time.

Reference: A First Course in Stochastic Processes, Second Edition 2nd Edition by Karlin & Taylor

Comment: Welcome to our site! If you refer to a book reference like Karlin, could you give a full citation including the publisher and edition number/year of publication? Without that, it's difficult for people to check out the same page as you. (With some books published internationally, even knowing which country's edition matters!)

Comment: Apologies. A First Course in Stochastic Processes, Second Edition 2nd Edition by Karlin & Taylor

Comment: Thanks for that! I suggest you edit it in to your answer. (There is an edit button at the bottom of your post.)